# Is taking the partial with one variable held constant the same as the derivative of that function?

Tags: notation, partial-derivative

Consider $u(x, y).$ Let $v = \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}.$ Now let $w(x) = u(x, 0).$ My question is, is $v(x, 0) = \frac{d w}{d x}?$ I have a feeling this is true but I'm not quite sure...

Comment: Yes, it is the same